# Formato de fecha y hora en Room android

Tags: android, mysqli, kotlin, android-room

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android, utilizando la librería Room.

Tengo un problema al establecer la hora, es que obtengo la fecha con la función datetime() en la consulta del DAO pero, cuando la muestra son dos horas menos que la hora actual. Creo que será problema de la zona horaria. Os dejo el código de mi DAO y una captura. Gracias

```
data class Task(
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  var id: Long,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "concept")
  var concept: String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "createAt")
  var createdAt: String,
//...
```

)

```
@Query("Insert  into task (concept,createAt,completed) values (:concept, DATETIME(), 0) ")
fun createTask(concept: String)
```

[image: Como se puede ver la hora no coincide con la del dispositivo.]

Como se puede ver la hora de la tarea, no coincide con la del dispositivo.

Comment: Es importante agregar como agregas el valor en tu aplicación.

Comment: La insert que utilizo la he puesto en la pregunta.

Comment: Me refiero a como obtienes ese valor y lo agregas en el Textview.